# shell output to rss

Tags: bash, shell, rss, cron, sh

I have a server running Ubuntu Linux. It does periodical tasks launched by cron and I would like to see output. Cron runs too often and I don't want to spam my mailbox, I would rather prefer to check it in Google reader once a day instead.

So, I need to put shell output into RSS or Atom feed. Is there any blog service able to generate RSS and accept posts from command line?

Comment: You can of course autolabel the e-mails in GMail and filter them out when reading e-mail; probably much simpler.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I've tried it before. It is simple, but I don't like it this way. First, Gmail will put them into one thread because subject is always the same, so I'll have to expand whole thread which can contain couple hundred messages. If I delete messages after reading, I can miss some important history messages (actual case). In case of RSS, Google Reader will display only last couple dozen of messages by default; I can share link to "blog" of my cron bot with another person; I never loose message history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can [post to blogger via email](http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=41452)